# How to revoke DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: permissions, microsoft

I've been playing around with Microsoft Graph in order to be able to send an email from within the Graph Explorer.

This was not possible, because my admin user with which I was logged in did not have Mail.Send permissions, so I clicked "Consent". The tests failed, so I wanted to revoke the Mail.Send permission, which I could only do by consenting to the DelegatedPermissionGrant.ReadWrite.All and Directory.ReadWrite.All permissions. Which I did.

After I revoked my Mail.Send permission, I wanted to revoke the other two, but as soon as I revoked one, I could no longer revoke the other - A needs B to be able to revoke A, and vice versa...

How can I revoke both these permissions from my admin account, and restore the original situation?

Comment: Is this [link](https://office365itpros.com/2023/05/04/graph-explorer-permissions/) related to your problem?

Comment: Thank you very much harrymc, that solved the problem!

Comment: Usually one lets the one who suggested the solution to also write the answer.

Comment: My apologies harrymc, I thought I'd spare you the work and add some information specific to my situation.

Comment: What's done is done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a link to the article [Removing Permissions from the Graph Explorer](https://office365itpros.com/2023/05/04/graph-explorer-permissions/) mentioned by harrymc I was able to unconsent to both permissions.

From the article: "One quick way to clear all the permissions is to close the Graph Explorer window and then delete the Graph Explorer app. Wait a few minutes afterwards and then launch the Graph Explorer and sign-in again. The Explorer detects that its app isn’t available in the tenant and will recreate it with no consented permissions. The same technique works for the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK app."

I deleted the app as stated above, and I can confirm that, after logging in again a few moments later, both permissions were revoked.